# Admin Extension redirects to frontend 404 page after update from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.0

Tags: admin, upgrade, 404-page

After I updated my Magento Shop from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.0 I have a problem with one extension. When I try to access the plugins backend pages (e.g. "Manage Pin" or "Manage Pin Order" I am always redirected to the frontends 404 page.

This is the plugins config.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

2.0.2

```
<global>

    <blocks>
         <pin>
            <class>HN_Pin_Block</class>
         </pin>

     <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>HN_Pin_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>   
     </adminhtml>

    </blocks>
    <helpers>
         <pin>
            <class>HN_Pin_Helper</class>
         </pin>
    </helpers>

    <models>
        <pin>
            <class>HN_Pin_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>pin_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </pin>
        <pin_mysql4>
            <class>HN_Pin_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <pin>
                    <table>pin</table>
                </pin>
                 <orderpin>
                    <table>orderpin</table>
                </orderpin>
                 <orderpin_status>
                    <table>orderpin_status</table>
                </orderpin_status>
                <ispinproduct>
                    <table>ispinproduct</table>
                </ispinproduct>
                <itempinbuy>
                    <table>itempinbuy</table>
                </itempinbuy>
                <orderpinbuy>
                    <table>orderpinbuy</table>
                </orderpinbuy>
            </entities>
        </pin_mysql4>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <pin_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>HN_Pin</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </pin_setup>
        <pin_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </pin_write>
        <pin_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </pin_read>
    </resources>    

 <template>
        <email>
           <pin_information_template>
               <label>Game licenses information</label>
               <file>pin_info.html</file>
               <type>html</type>
           </pin_information_template>

           <low_pinstock_template>
               <label>PIN Low stock notification</label>
               <file>pin_low_stock_notification.html</file>
               <type>html</type>
           </low_pinstock_template>
        </email>
    </template>
    <events>
      <customer_save_after>
      <observers>
                <pin_observer>
                    <class>pin/observer</class>
                    <method>customerGroupChangeListener</method>
                </pin_observer>
            </observers>
      </customer_save_after>

        <sales_order_item_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <pin_observer>
                    <class>pin/observer</class>
                    <method>savePinOrderItem</method>
                </pin_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_item_save_commit_after>
        <sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <pin_observer>
                    <class>pin/observer</class>
                    <method>orderCommitListener</method>
                </pin_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_commit_after>
     </events>
</global>


<frontend>
    <routers>
        <pin>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>HN_Pin</module>
                <frontName>pin</frontName>
            </args>
        </pin>

    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <pin>
                <file>hn_pin.xml</file>
            </pin>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <pin before="Mage_Adminhtml">HN_Pin_Adminhtml</pin>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
        <menu>
        <pin module="pin">
            <title>Pin management</title>
            <sort_order>171</sort_order>
            <children>
                <items module="pin">
                    <title>Manage PIN</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>pin/adminhtml_pin/index</action>
                </items>
                <order module="pin">
                    <title>Manage PIN Order</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>pin/adminhtml_order/index</action>
                </order>
                <pinproduct translate="title" module="catalog">
                        <title>Manage Pin Product</title>
                        <action>pin/adminhtml_pin/pinproduct/</action>
                    </pinproduct>
             </children>
        </pin>
    </menu>
        <layout>
        <updates>
            <pin>
                <file>hn_pin.xml</file>
            </pin>
        </updates>
    </layout>

     <acl>
        <resources>
             <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <pin translate="title" module="pin">
                                        <title>Game license delivery Settings</title>
                                    </pin>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                        </system>
                </children>


            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
<default>   
    <pin>
        <general>
            <change_status>1</change_status>
            <email_sender>sales</email_sender>
            <qty_sync>1</qty_sync>
            <delivery_confirmed>0</delivery_confirmed>
            <low_stock_notification>1</low_stock_notification>
            <low_stock_number>10</low_stock_number>
            <show_pin_successpage>1</show_pin_successpage>
        </general>          
    </pin>

</default>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <notification_low_pin>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>pin/observer::scheduledSend</model>
            </run>
        </notification_low_pin>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

I hope you can help me :x

Greetings